# Access the DocuSign API in your Force.com / Salesforce.com account in order to send an object with a single click of a button

Tags: docusignapi

## DocuSignAPI for Salesforce.

Hello everybody, I'm following this manual   to access the DocuSign API in  Force.com / Salesforce.com account in order to send an object with a single click of a button to be isgned.

http://developer.force.com/cookbook/recipe/accessing-docusign-api-from-salesforcecom-to-send-contracts-for-esignatures

the problems is when i get the next error:

"The DocuSign EnvelopeId:Exception - System.CalloutException: Web service callout failed: WebService returned a SOAP Fault: The email address for the recipient is invalid. The recipient Id follows. faultcode=soap:Client faultactor=https://demo.docusign.net/api/3.0/dsapi.asmx"

Do anyone know the solution?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Re your specific error, I suggest that you download the API call logging information from DocuSign itself to see exactly what you sent to DocuSign via Salesforce.

In general for Salesforce/DocuSign integration, recommended first step is to use DocuSign for Salesforce, available from the Salesforce app store.

Additional developer information and source code is available from [this blog post](https://www.docusign.com/blog/dsdev-salesforce-recipes-now-available/). It includes info on recipes (including source code) from DocuSign that document how to call the DocuSign API from Salesforce.

One issue to watch out for: you can't send PDFs from Salesforce to DocuSign due to callout limitations enforced by Salesforce.

Solutions:

1. you can make a call to a gateway (which you write). Your gateway would then *pull* the doc from Salesforce and then send it to DocuSign
2. Or use DocuSign for Salesforce which does the above for you.

Comment: Suppose I am using DocuSign and I need to insert Status of Document in Object.

Comment: Hi @NatavarGhodasara, Please ask a new question, including a description of what you've tried so far. In general, if you want to update an SFDC object when a DocuSign envelope status changes then I'd recommend using DocuSign Connect to trigger a program which then updates SFDC via their API.

Answer (score 0):

thank you for your answer.

At the end the solution was that the email of the person that I wanted to send the document to sign didnt exist :P.

But now my problem is How can I update the Docusign status? becouse when I put this in an "execute anonymous windows" that creates me a Status:

dsfs__DocuSign_Status__c status = new  dsfs__DocuSign_Status__c();

```
            status.dsfs__Contract__c='0293900000xD';

            status.dsfs__Envelope_Status__c='Sent';

            upsert status;
```

but when i use this inside of a controller extension:

try {

```
        DocuSignAPI.EnvelopeStatus es  = dsApiSend.CreateAndSendEnvelope(envelope);

        envelopeId = es.EnvelopeID;          
        // this.contract.DocuSign_Status__c=es.Status;          
            dsfs__DocuSign_Status__c status = new  dsfs__DocuSign_Status__c();
            status.dsfs__Contract__c=this.contract.Id;
            status.dsfs__Envelope_Status__c=es.Status;
            upsert status;


    } catch ( CalloutException e) {
        System.debug('Exception - ' + e );
        envelopeId = 'Exception - ' + e;
    }
```

Doesn't work, the Status is never created.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: The solution was that I was doing the "UPSERT" operation inside the constructor of the Apex Class controller and seems like you can't do DML operation inside of the Apex Class controller.

But I put the "upsert" in other function and know is inserting well.